# @XmlJavaTypeAdapter not being called when used with @XmlSeeAlso

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb, xml-serialization, jaxb2

I can't get the XmlJavaTypeAdapter working when it is set at class-level on a subclass of an abstract class annotated with XmlSeeAlso. The serialization is done but the adapter is never being called.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class TopLevelClassBeingSerialized {
private Set<MyAbstractClass> set = new HashSet();
}

@XmlSeeAlso({MyImplClass.class})
//@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyAbstractClassAdapter.class)
public class MyAbstractClass {

}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyImplClassAdapter.class)
public class MyImplClass {
private int test = 2;
}
```

When the comment is uncommented, the adapter is called. I have also tried the setAdapter() method and it doesn't work. Is this a limitation of JAXB? If yes what's the best and cleanest workaround?

Comment: I don't understand.It is not the same declared adapter